# Zend Amf security

Tags: actionscript-3, zend-framework, zend-amf

We basically deveolop flash games and it's often hacked by others. so am thinking of using zenamf. I would like to know more about secured zend conection. Is it possible to access the zend endpoint by a specific swf hosted in a server?

Comment: Somewhat avoiding your question, but why do you think using zend-amf for communication is going to fix your issues? Do you even know the vector people are using to "hack" your games? Given that you normally can't trust the client, I'm not sure how securing the communication layer helps you.

Comment: Actualy i need to communicate safely with server. I know it's not 100% possible. But need to know is there any possible solution whichh may make it difficult.

Comment: How are you doing it at the moment? Could you not just use SSL? Again though, it's unlikely this is the vector being used to tamper with your game data.

Comment: currently am using secure swf to secure my swf file. Am using zendamf for saving data. But it's http . That's it.

Comment: I have achieved this by saving data at a time interval and then comparing it with final data. I almost saved it but it's not completely secure.

Comment: by using zend it's become easy to communicate with the server rather than safety.